# How can I NOW say that I took a decision about my FUTURE in my PAST?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, tenses, past-tense, syntactic-analysis

> *At this point of time, **I WAS certain that software industry IS not where I want TO BE. Neither the advertising agency.** I wanted to practice this lifestyle and learn many things. So, I submitted my resignation in December 2013.*

I mean - I was certain (at some stage of my past) that Software and Advertising are not the industries in which I would want to look myself in(in future).

So, the sentence in italics needs to be corrected accordingly.

Comment: _At this point in time, I was certain that neither the software industry nor advertising was where I wanted to be. Instead I wanted to practice a certain lifestyle and learn more things, hence I submitted my resignation in December 2013._

Comment: Thank you.
But, My own sentence "At this point in/of time, I was certain..." is sounding like "After that point in time, I was uncertain.."  But, in reality, Submitting my resignation is a Right decision even today.  
 
Or can I write it this way?

"By this time, I was certain that neither the software industry nor the advertising was where I wanted to be. Instead, I wanted to practice this lifestyle and learn more things. Hence, I submitted my resignation in December 2013.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by "this lifestyle"  Anyway: _At that point in time, I realised that neither the software industry_ will convey that at that point it became clear

Comment: Why are these phrases-"At this point in/of time", "By this time"- there? You wan to talk now about a decision you took in the past about your future. You are saying now: "I had been certain that I would have been neither in software nor in advertising industry. I had  wanted the life style now I am in and learn many things. So, I submitted my resignation in December 2013"

Answer (score 1):

> At this point of time, I WAS certain that software industry IS not
>   where I want TO BE. Neither the advertising agency. I wanted to
>   practice this lifestyle and learn many things. So, I submitted my
>   resignation in December 2013.

You're mixing tenses here.

I think the correct version should be:

At that point in time, I was certain that neither the software industry, nor an advertising agency, was where I wanted to be.

....

You then say that you "wanted to practice THIS..."... Which lifestyle?

So, you have to change it...

"I wanted to practice ... and learn many things; therefore, I submitted my resignation in December 2013."

Comment: You need to drop that "not".  (fixed now)

Comment: @swbarnes2 Good spot.

Answer (score -1):

At this point *in* time, I **was** certain that the software industry **was** not where I **would want** to be [in the future].